# $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $\Gamma=\{\gamma(t)|t\in[a,b]\}$, image of $\gamma$. When is $m(\Gamma)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Denote by $\Gamma=\{\gamma(t)|t\in[a,b]\}$, image of $\gamma$.

I know if $f$ is continuous then image is not of measure zero. For example take space filing curve(Peano curve?).

But what if I add a extra condition that  function $\gamma$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is rectifiable then its image has content zero.

**Proof** (for $n=2$; can be extended to $n>2$.)

Let $R\subset\Bbb R^2$ be a square such that $\Gamma\subset R$. Assume without oso of generality that its sides have length $2$. Divide $R$ into $4\,n^2$ equal squares of side $1/n^2$. Clasify them into four classes $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$ y $D_n$, each one containing $n^2$ squares, such that if $R_1$, $R_2$ are two different squares in the same group and $p_i\in R_i$, then $|p_1-p_2|\ge1/n$.

Suppose that for some $n$ $\Gamma$ has non empty intersection with at least $n\sqrt n$ squares in $A_n$. Then, considering a polygonal with a point in each of the squares, we have
$$
\operatorname{length}(\gamma)\ge n\sqrt{n}\,\frac1n=\sqrt n\,.
$$
Since $\gamma$ is rectifiable, there exists $n_A$ such that $\Gamma$ has non empty intersection with less than $n\,\sqrt{n}$ squares in $A_{n}$ for all $n\ge n_A$. The sum of the areas of all those squares is bounded by
$$
n\,\sqrt{n}\,\frac1{n^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\,.
$$
Repeating the argument with $B_n$, $C_n$ and $D_n$ we see that if $n\ge\max(n_A,n_B,n_C,n_D)$, entonces $\Gamma$  is contained ia set of squares of total area bounded by $4/\sqrt n$.

Comment: I understand your point. I have one last question. Can you given a concrete example of a differentiable map $\gamma$ such that image does not have content zero.Thanks

Comment: Differentiable $\implies$ rectifiable

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240650/show-that-this-path-is-differentiable-but-not-rectifiable

Comment: $$\gamma:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R, \space \gamma(t):=
\begin{cases}
\ (0,0)  & \text{if $t$=0} \\[2ex]
t,t^2 \cos (\frac{\pi}{t^2}), & \text{if $t$ $\in$ [-1,1]\ {0}}
\end{cases}$$ differentiable but not rectifiable

Comment: @Tensor_Product Oops! I was thinking $C^1$ (or more generally, piecewise $C^1$.)

Comment: Yeah you are right $C^1$ implies Lipschitz and from there it follows easily.Thanks for your answer. Have a good day.